# How do I make the grid lines in a JavaFX TableView stay sharp?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

The code below creates a TableView with enough columns to require a horizontal scroll bar.

Initially the grid lines in the TableView have a width of one pixel and because of this are sharp.

Scroll to the far right of the TableView and all of a sudden the grid lines have a width of two pixels, one lighter than the other.

This makes the grid lines look blurry.

It is probably caused by JavaFX thinking the grid lines are at a fractional point (after the scrolling) rather than exactly on the pixel and so blending the grid line with it's surroundings.

How do I tell JavaFX not to do this?

Can I change the scroll so that it only ever chooses exact pixel boundaries?

Thanks.

In the code below I change the grid line colour to red (using css) to make it obvious, however the same problem occurs if the default colour is used.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableTest4 extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, 500, 500);
        String cssFile = getClass().getResource("tabletest4.css").toExternalForm();
        scene.getStylesheets().add(cssFile);
        stage.setScene(scene);

        TableView<Integer> table = new TableView<>();

        ObservableList<Integer> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            data.add(i);
        }
        table.setItems(data);

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            String text = "";
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                text = "sdfd";
            } else if (i % 3 == 0) {
                text = "dghg hghj";
            } else if (i == 17) {
                text = "This Hopppsdssss";
            }
            TableColumn<Integer,String> column = new TableColumn<>(Integer.toString(i) + " " + text);
            column.setCellValueFactory(param -> new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>(param.getValue().toString()));
            table.getColumns().add(column);
        }

        borderPane.setCenter(table);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

and the css is:

```
.table-view{
    -fx-table-cell-border-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it looks like it isn't possible by just using css so I have entered a bug report that should be fixed by 8u40. https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-38781